# Adding collision detection to render function is freezing in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, collision-detection, game-physics

I am learning threejs by doing some handson practice. I have a car, track and building in my scene. I want to detect collision of car to building and off track.

I have seen some examples collision detection from https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Collision-Detection.html and added the same code provided by Stemkoski.

But when I try to add the function in my render function, it is slowing my computer.

Also, I want to detect the collision if the car is out of track and when it touches the building.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the full code.

https://github.com/chintuyadavsara/car-game

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are casting a ray for each vertex of your car, and then compute the intersected objects for each; that can be compute-intensive.

If you don't need a high collision precision and your car and the collision objects fit rather well into boxes, you could use the bounding box(es) of your car and check if it intersects the bounding boxes of other objects, e.g. buildings.

See:

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Box3

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Box3.setFromObject

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Box3.intersectsBox